# Windows 2012 hyper-v saying degraded (integration services upgrade required) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, windows-server-2012, hyper-v-server-2012

I have upgraded my Ubuntu 12.04 that runs under hyper-v Windows 2012 server, and since then, hyper-v manager reports that I need to upgrade my integration services under Ubuntu. But I cannot find how to upgrade it, or what to do.

Answer (score 3):

No upgrade is necessary - [Microsoft themselves tell you to ignore the "Degraded integration services message for non-Windows guests"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2956569).

Answer (score 2):

Logon to your hypervisor and open up the Hyper-V Manager. Then select the virtual machine and open it up in the console. In the Action menu of the console, you can choose to 'Insert Integration Services Setup Disk' in your virtual machine. Then logon to you virtual machine and autorun the disk.

Comment: I was under the impression that Ubuntu 12.04 already have integration services build in? And this was working ok until I made apt-get upgrade...

Comment: I order to this guy (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=2830): 
"However, notice that in the Hyper-V Manager console, you will have a warning stating that the conditions are degraded and you should install Linux integration services."